# Spring security - SessionRegistry getAllPrincipals.size() is 0 when using Programmatically login in a user

Tags: spring-security

I want to get all logged in users and using the following code :

```
sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
```

Everything is working fine when i use login form to login the user. But, when i login the user Programmatically(using Spring Security) with the help of following code:

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Then `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size()` return 0.